# How to append to Buffer in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

Say I have a Buffer:

```
let b = Buffer.from('');
```

how can I append to `b`? Is the only way to create a new Buffer?

```
b = Buffer.concat([b, z]);
```

on the same subject, is there a way to create a dynamic sized buffer, or should I use Array instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To create a dynamic buffer use an array then `concat` the array similar to this:

```
let chunks = []

stream
  .on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk))
  .on('close', () => console.log(Buffer.concat(chunks)))
```

Comment: I would think `Buffer.from(chunks)` makes more sense? idk

Comment: It might work, but all the examples that I have seen use `concat`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10356183/1778465